# Facing issues while implementing Spring Security with http-basic authentication for spring rest API

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi i am new to spring security and trying to implement it in my project.

I am trying to use UserDetailsService of spring security to achieve the security.
well i have configured every thing from web.xml to spring-security.xml
i am facing an compilation issue while autowiring the DAO class in the class that implements UserDetailsService. If i do not autowire then the code is compiling successfully and when i am testing the code from postman i am getting an error as follow's

```
12:13:45.738 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher - No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
12:13:45.738 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.w.BasicAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
```

and below is my web.xml

```
     <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
                    classpath:spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and my spring-security.xml files contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="user.app.security.DemoAppEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/auth/login"/>
    </bean>

    <security:http use-expressions="true"  create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login"  access="hasAnyRole('UserAppAdmin','HR','manager')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern='/user/**' access="hasAnyRole('UserAppAdmin','HR','manager')"/>
        <security:http-basic />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>


    <bean id="userappAuthenticationProvider" class="user.app.security.UserappAuthenticationProvider" />

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userappAuthenticationProvider">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

my UserappAuthenticationProvider class

```
public class UserappAuthenticationProvider implements UserDetailsService{

    // Is it neccessary to autowire this object
    // And this is causing problem when i am trying to autowire it's giving compilation error 
    private FarmerDAO farmerdao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserLogin farmer = farmerdao.getUserByLogin(userName);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        UserApp principal = null;
        principal = new UserApp(authorities,farmer.getUserId(), farmer.getUserName(), farmer.getRtn(), farmer);
        String role=farmer.getRole();
        System.out.println(farmer);
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        return principal;
    }   
}
```

The compilation error is as follow if autowire:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [user.app.service.FarmerDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

And one thing when i am testing from postman and debugging the application.
the request comes till the line

```
FarmerLogin farmer = farmerService.getUserByLogin(userName);
```

of UserappAuthenticationProvider class and throws the error as show at the beginning of the post.

Please suggest me if i am missing some part so, that i can successfully authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you've provided here, there is no sign of defining the farmerdao bean in the xmls, and the userappAuthenticationProvider does not have any setter for it and its bean did not set the property to it. so I think this is your problem.

In my experience, it is better to use one mode, xml or annotation. and I prefer xml.

the result will be like this :

```
 <bean id="farmerdao" class="user.app.security.FarmerDaoImpl">
    <!-- set the required attributes to connect your dao to the DB -->
 <bean>

 <bean id="userappAuthenticationProvider" class="user.app.security.UserappAuthenticationProvider">
   <property name="farmerdao" ref="farmerdao"/>
 </bean>
```

and of course you need to define a setter for farmerdao in your UserappAuthenticationProvider.

Comment: pls can you share how can i set the farmerdao in the xml

Comment: hey thanks for the sample code but, now i am implementing the farmerdao in the FarmerDaoImpl class itself and i m using another interface inside the FarmerDaoImpl class which is Autowire and that talk to the database. and that interface is FarmerService and i m using mybatis as an orm tool. so now how i can achive the authentication. Please suggest

Comment: If your dependencies are wired correctly, then the logic is up to you. it seems that the sample you have wrote in the question can work. But I don't know the exact logic you need to be implemented. if you be more specific, I would be able to help you